# SQL Server, can SQL Server store 10 pieces of information of item in a row?

Tags: sql-server

I'm wondering if SQL Server can store 10 pieces of information of item in a row?

Because I want to make a table of Date, Item_Name, Quantity

but I want to make in a row that input only 1 date (ex. 21 November 2014) but have Item name such as (chicken, rabbit, cow) that have quantity of (2, 4, 3)

Can SQL do that ??

If not, can you recommend me, because I want to make a daily report of what items have sold on the day and the day before and so on.

Can you understand what I meant? Cause I'm not good with english.

Comment: The **first normal form** of database design says that any given cell should **never** contain multiple pieces of information. Why do you want to do this?? The way to store a "list" or "array" in a relational database is to use **multiple rows** in a table

Comment: because I want to have only 1 row per day, because seeing 50 items (or 50 rows) input per day is too much.
So I can do this by using the multiple rows ?
thanks.

Comment: Really, really, horribly bad design .... have **one row per day** in your "master" table, but if you have 10 or more rows per day, create a **child table** that links to the master and stores **one piece of information per row**. Database normalization is there **for a good reason!** Don't just ignore it and work against it - you'll regret it bitterly, later on, when maintaining this database

Comment: So you want to make a ridiculous design because you can not program enough to present it nicely to the user otherwise? Seriously?

Comment: I'm just a student here, I still not get anything about program, so it's better to do that ??
when I'm thinking about it, maybe it is simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the information guys.
it's bad to use the multiple rows then.
I will use the simple one.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do something like this:

```
Table Dates:
DateId    Date
1         21/11/2014
2         23/11/2014

Table Items:
DateId    Name       Quantity
1         Chicken    2
1         Rabbit     4
1         Cow        3
2         Dinosaur   666
```

`Dates.DateId` should be Primary Key and, depending on your logic, perhaps also identity (it autogenerates the following id), and `Items.DateId` should have a Foreign Key with `Dates.DateId`.

More info about normalization [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).